# Android ML Kit throws FirebseMLException for input type

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I am trying detect whole person in single image. So, I refered [this steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models#kotlin+ktx_8) and build app downloaded detect.tflite file and labelmap.txt as per guide and buil app.

Code `MainActivity.kt`:

```
private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var mContext: Activity
private var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(mBinding.root)
    mContext = this

    val localModel = FirebaseCustomLocalModel.Builder()
            .setAssetFilePath("detect.tflite")
            .build()
    val options = FirebaseModelInterpreterOptions.Builder(localModel).build()
    val interpreter = createLocalModelInterpreter()

    val inputOutputOptions = FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
            .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.INT32, intArrayOf(1, 224))
            .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.INT32, intArrayOf(1, 143))
            .build()

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.image_asset)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    setLoading(false)
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    bitmap = (resource as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                    setLoading(false)
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(mBinding.ivSample)

    mBinding.btnDetect.setOnClickListener {
        bitmap?.let {
            setLoading(true)
            val imgData = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(it)

            try {
                // Create model inputs from our image data.
                val modelInputs = FirebaseModelInputs.Builder().add(imgData).build()

                // Perform inference using our model interpreter.
                interpreter?.run(modelInputs, inputOutputOptions)
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            setLoading(false)
                            Log.e("ImageDetect>>>", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
                        }
                        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                            setLoading(false)
                            val inferenceOutput = result?.getOutput<Array<ByteArray>>(0)!!
                            val probabilities = inferenceOutput[0]
                            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(assets.open("labelmap.txt")))
                            for (i in probabilities.indices) {
                                val label = reader.readLine()
                                Log.i("ImageDetect>>>", String.format("%s: %1.4f", label, probabilities[i]))
                            }
                        }
            } catch (exc: FirebaseMLException) {

            }

            /*
            objectDetector.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { detectedObjects ->
                        setLoading(false)
                        detectObjects(detectedObjects)
                        Log.i("ImageDetect>>>", "Detected")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        setLoading(false)
                        Log.e("ImageDetect>>>", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
                    }*/

            /*val labeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(ImageLabelerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

            labeler.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { labels ->
                        setLoading(false)
                        Log.i("ImageDetect>>>", "Detected")
                        for (label in labels) {
                            val text = label.text
                            val confidence = label.confidence
                            val index = label.index

                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        setLoading(false)
                        Log.e("ImageDetect>>>", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
                    }*/
        }
    }
}

private fun createLocalModelInterpreter(): FirebaseModelInterpreter {
    val localModelName = resources.assets.list("")?.firstOrNull { it.endsWith(".tflite") }
            ?: throw(RuntimeException("Don't forget to add the tflite file to your assets folder"))
    Log.d("ImageDetect>>>", "Local model found: $localModelName")

    // Create an interpreter with the local model asset
    val localModel = FirebaseCustomLocalModel.Builder().setAssetFilePath(localModelName).build()
    val localInterpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(
            FirebaseModelInterpreterOptions.Builder(localModel).build())!!
    Log.d("ImageDetect>>>", "Local model interpreter initialized")

    // Return the interpreter
    return localInterpreter
}

private fun convertBitmapToByteBuffer(b: Bitmap): ByteArray {
    val bytes: Int = b.byteCount
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes) //Create a new buffer
    b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer) //Move the byte data to the buffer
    return buffer.array()
}

private fun setLoading(isShow: Boolean) {
    if (isShow) mBinding.pbLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    else mBinding.pbLoading.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Here I just used local model which is base model from [TensorFlow starter model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview). After all setup I run app and local model interpreter initialized successfully. But on button click I am trying to analyse image detect person from it.

Then getting error:

```
com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Input 0 should be 2 type, but found 3 type.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzrj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter@@22.0.3:55)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzrj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter@@22.0.3:147)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:31)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqd.call(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:32)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpw.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:6)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

What is the problem with input type I can't understand is there problem with `inputOutputOptions.setInputFormat()`? Or some other type of error?